# TypeError: not enough arguments for format string while importing CSV to MySQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I wish to import my .csv file to a table 'testcsv' in MySQL using Python, but I'm unable to do so because I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 2, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query,r)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 184, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

My code looks like this:

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
    port=3306,
    user='root',
    passwd='tulip',
    db='frompython')
cursor = mydb.cursor()

csv_data = csv.reader(file('C:\Users\Tulip\Desktop\New_Sheet.csv'))

row_count = sum(1 for row in csv_data)

query = """INSERT INTO testcsv (number, name, marks) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"""

for r in range(1, row_count):
    cursor.execute(query,r)
```

I've tried every possible answer given to the related questions here, but none of them worked for me. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for r in range(1, row_count):
```

just iterates over numbers, i.e. in the first iteration `r = 1`. Remove the line defining `row_count` and get the actual rows:

```
for r in csv_data:
```